# Execute a Terminal Command using AppleScript (Mountain Lion)

Tags: macos, terminal, applescript

This used to work in pre-Mountain Lion OS X:

```
tell application "Terminal"
    activate
    do script "cd /"
end tell
```

Now, the new bash window is opened, but **nothing is executed**, *no mater what the command-line script*.

It's broken on the few systems I've tried it on, but is it a general problem? Is there a workaround?

Comment: @digiMonk Brilliant! Along with Reynhout's comments, this made me revisit the Startup options. You're right -- changing "Shell opens with" to "default login shell" fixes it.

Comment: Cool, I write it as answer

Answer (score 1):

Works as expected for me.

Any recent changes to your environment or .bashrc?

```
bash$ cat t.applescript 
tell application "Terminal"
    activate
    do script "cd /"
end tell
```

```
bash$ osascript t.applescript
tab 1 of window id 9766
```

New Terminal window opens, "cd /" is visible in buffer, and shell is at /.

```
bash$ uname -smr
Darwin 12.2.0 x86_64
```

Edit: verified on 10.8.3 too

```
bash$ uname -smr
Darwin 12.3.0 x86_64
```

Comment: I think my edit overlapped your comment -- just to be sure, I tested on 12.3.0 as well, same results. One idea: try creating a new user and doing the test there. That would rule out anything in your environment.

Answer (score 1):

Check Terminal.app's Preferences, there are many options for new windows and what Shell to open at startup and many more–